# Cannot run SKAction sequence before nodes are removed in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to run a sequence when sprites are removed from my scene.

I added a boolean fruitScaled to try to break up the sequence and the `SKAction.wait` to let the animation complete before removal. The sprites are getting removed from the scene but the animation does not run, the sprites get removed instantly.

How can I get the SKAction to run on the sprites before they get removed from the scene?

```
var fruitScaled = false

func removeFruit() {
    // Removing Specific Children
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "fruitButton") {
           (node, stop) in
        if node.name == "fruitButton" {
            if self.fruitScaled == false {
                let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.5)
                let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scale, wait])
                node.run(sequence)
                print("Fruit scaled down")

                self.fruitScaled = true
            }

            if self.fruitScaled == true {
                node.removeFromParent();
                print("Removed old fruits")
            }
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an important SKAction you can use in this case

```
let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.5)
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scale, wait, remove])
node.run(sequence)
```

if that didn't exist you could run it in a block

```
let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.5)
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))

let blowup = SKAction.run { self.blowUp() }

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scale, wait, blowup])
node.run(sequence)
```

FYI the problem with your code above is that the

```
self.fruitScaled = true
```

gets set immediately (it has no knowledge of your wait loop).  To run it with the Boolean it has to get set after the wait

```
let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.5)
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
let change = SKAction.run { self.fruitScaled = true }
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scale, wait, change])
```